# Distributed decentralized ring

Tags: erlang

I am trying to implement a distributed ring in Erlang, in which each node will store data.

My idea was create a `gen_server` module **node_ring** which will provide state of node in ring:

```
-record(nodestate, {id, hostname, previd, nextid, prevnodename, nextnodename, data}).
```

Next, I created virtual hosts via:

```
werl -sname node -setcookie cook
werl -sname node1 -setcookie cook
werl -sname node2 -setcookie cook
```

In the first node: *node@Machine* I start the first item in the ring:

```
**(node@Machine)1> node_ring:start_link()**
```

Functions:

```
start_link() ->
    {Hostname, Id} = {'node@Machine', 0},
    {ok, Pid} = gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [first, Hostname, Id], []).
```

and:

```
init([first, Hostname, Id]) ->          
            State = #nodestate{id = Id, hostname = Hostname, previd = Id, nextid = Id, prevnode = Hostname, nextnode = Hostname, data = dict:new()},
            {ok, State}.
```

In the next node: `**(node1@Machine)1>**` I want to start the same module node_ring,
but I have no idea how link it with the previous item in the ring and how the next node will know which node and `node_ring` is started.

Can you somebody explain me, how make distributed ring in Erlang? I know that there are some implemented systems like Riak. I looked into the source code, but I am really new to distributed Erlang programming, and I do not understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distributed systems programming is hard.  It's hard to understand.  It's hard to implement correctly.

The source code for [riak_core](https://github.com/basho/riak_core) can be very hard to understand at first.  Here are some resources that helped me better understand riak_core:

- [Where to Start with Riak Core](http://basho.com/where-to-start-with-riak-core/) (specifically, [Try Try Try](https://github.com/rzezeski/try-try-try) by Ryan Zezeski)
- Any of the riak_core projects in [project-fifo](https://github.com/project-fifo).  [howl](https://github.com/project-fifo/howl) is probably the smallest project built on top of riak_core that is fairly easy to understand.
- Understand that at the heart of riak_core is a consistent hashing algorithm that allows it to distribute data and work across the ring using partitions in a uniform manner: [Why Riak Just Works](https://basho.com/why-riak-just-works/)

  - A while ago I wrote [erlang-ryng](https://github.com/redis-sd/erlang-ryng) which is a generic consistent hash algorithm handler for rings.  It may be helpful for understanding the purpose of consistent hashing in the context of a ring.
- Understanding how [riak_pipe](https://github.com/basho/riak_pipe) works also helped me better grasp how work can be distributed in a uniform manner.

In regards to "It's hard to implement correctly", you can read the [Jepsen posts by aphyr](https://aphyr.com/tags/jepsen) for examples and cases where major databases and distributed storage systems have or previously had issues in their own implementations.

That said, here is a very simplistic implementation of a ring in Erlang, however it still has many holes that are addressed below:

```
-module(node_ring).
-behaviour(gen_server).

% Public API
-export([start_link/0]).
-export([erase/1]).
-export([find/1]).
-export([store/2]).

% Ring API
-export([join/1]).
-export([nodes/0]).
-export([read/1]).
-export([write/1]).
-export([write/2]).

% gen_server
-export([init/1]).
-export([handle_call/3]).
-export([handle_cast/2]).
-export([handle_info/2]).
-export([terminate/2]).
-export([code_change/3]).

-record(state, {
    node = node()        :: node(),
    ring = ordsets:new() :: ordsets:ordset(node()),
    data = dict:new()    :: dict:dict(term(), term())
}).

% Public API
start_link() ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [], []).

erase(Key) ->
    write({erase, Key}).

find(Key) ->
    read({find, Key}).

store(Key, Value) ->
    write({store, Key, Value}).

% Ring API
join(Node) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {join, Node}).

nodes() ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, nodes).

read(Request) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {read, Request}).

write(Request) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {write, Request}).

write(Node, Request) ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, {write, Node, Request}).

% gen_server
init([]) ->
    State = #state{},
    {ok, State}.

handle_call({join, Node}, _From, State=#state{node=Node}) ->
    {reply, ok, State};
handle_call({join, Peer}, From, State=#state{node=Node, ring=Ring}) ->
    case net_adm:ping(Peer) of
        pong ->
            case ordsets:is_element(Peer, Ring) of
                true ->
                    {reply, ok, State};
                false ->
                    monitor_node(Peer, true),
                    NewRing = ordsets:add_element(Peer, Ring),
                    spawn(fun() ->
                        rpc:multicall(Ring, ?MODULE, join, [Peer])
                    end),
                    spawn(fun() ->
                        Reply = rpc:call(Peer, ?MODULE, join, [Node]),
                        gen_server:reply(From, Reply)
                    end),
                    {noreply, State#state{ring=NewRing}}
            end;
        pang ->
            {reply, {error, connection_failed}, State}
    end;
handle_call(nodes, _From, State=#state{node=Node, ring=Ring}) ->
    {reply, ordsets:add_element(Node, Ring), State};
handle_call({read, Request}, From, State) ->
    handle_read(Request, From, State);
handle_call({write, Request}, From, State=#state{node=Node, ring=Ring}) ->
    spawn(fun() ->
        rpc:multicall(Ring, ?MODULE, write, [Node, Request])
    end),
    handle_write(Request, From, State);
handle_call({write, Node, _Request}, _From, State=#state{node=Node}) ->
    {reply, ok, State};
handle_call({write, _Peer, Request}, From, State) ->
    handle_write(Request, From, State);
handle_call(_Request, _From, State) ->
    {reply, ignore, State}.

handle_cast(_Request, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_info({nodedown, Peer}, State=#state{ring=Ring}) ->
    NewRing = ordsets:del_element(Peer, Ring),
    {noreply, State#state{ring=NewRing}};
handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

terminate(_Reason, _State) ->
    ok.

code_change(_OldVsn, State, _Extra) ->
    {ok, State}.

%% @private
handle_read({find, Key}, _From, State=#state{data=Data}) ->
    {reply, dict:find(Key, Data), State}.

%% @private
handle_write({erase, Key}, _From, State=#state{data=Data}) ->
    {reply, ok, State#state{data=dict:erase(Key, Data)}};
handle_write({store, Key, Value}, _From, State=#state{data=Data}) ->
    {reply, ok, State#state{data=dict:store(Key, Value, Data)}}.
```

If we start 3 different nodes with the `-sname` set to `node0`, `node1`, and `node2`:

```
erl -sname node0 -setcookie cook -run node_ring start_link
erl -sname node1 -setcookie cook -run node_ring start_link
erl -sname node2 -setcookie cook -run node_ring start_link
```

Here's how we join a node to the ring:

```
(node0@localhost)1> node_ring:nodes().
['node0@localhost']
(node0@localhost)2> node_ring:join('node1@localhost').
ok
(node0@localhost)3> node_ring:nodes().
['node0@localhost', 'node1@localhost']
```

If we run `node_ring:nodes()` on `node1` we get:

```
(node1@localhost)1> node_ring:nodes().
['node0@localhost', 'node1@localhost']
```

Now let's go to `node2` and join one of the other two nodes:

```
(node2@localhost)1> node_ring:nodes().
['node2@localhost']
(node2@localhost)2> node_ring:join('node0localhost').
ok
(node2@localhost)3> node_ring:nodes().
['node0@localhost', 'node1@localhost',
 'node2@localhost']
```

Notice how both `node0` and `node1` were added to `node2`, even though we only specified `node0` on the join.  This means if we had hundreds of nodes, we would only need to join one of them in order to join the entire ring.

Now we can use `store(Key, Value)` on any of the nodes and it will be replicated to the other two:

```
(node0@localhost)4> node_ring:store(mykey, myvalue).
ok
```

Let's try reading `mykey` from the other two, first `node1`:

```
(node1@localhost)2> node_ring:find(mykey).
{ok,myvalue}
```

Then `node2`:

```
(node2@localhost)4> node_ring:find(mykey).
{ok,myvalue}
```

Let's use `erase(Key)` on `node2` and try to read the key again on the other nodes:

```
(node2@localhost)5> node_ring:erase(mykey).
ok
```

On `node0`:

```
(node0@localhost)5> node_ring:find(mykey).
error
```

On `node1`:

```
(node1@localhost)3> node_ring:find(mykey).
error
```

Awesome!  We have a distributed decentralized ring that can act as a simple key/value store!  That was easy, not hard at all!  As long as we don't have any nodes go down, packet loss, network partitions, nodes added to the ring, or some other form of chaos, we have a near-perfect solution here.  In reality, however, you have to account for all of those things in order to have a system that won't drive you crazy in the long run.

Here's a brief example of something our little `node_ring` can't handle:

1. `node1` goes down
2. `node0` stores key `a` and value `1`
3. `node1` comes back up and joins the ring
4. `node1` tries to find key `a`

First, let's kill `node1`.  If we check the nodes on `node0`:

```
(node0@localhost)6> node_ring:nodes().
['node0@localhost','node2@localhost']
```

And on `node2`:

```
(node2@localhost)6> node_ring:nodes().
['node0@localhost','node2@localhost']
```

We see that `node1` has been removed from the ring automatically.  Let's store something on `node0`:

```
(node0@localhost)7> node_ring:store(a, 1).
ok
```

And read it from `node2`:

```
(node2@localhost)7> node_ring:find(a).
{ok,1}
```

Let's start up `node1` again and join the ring:

```
(node1@localhost)1> node_ring:join('node0@localhost').
ok
(node1@localhost)2> node_ring:nodes().
['node0@localhost','node1@localhost',
 'node2@localhost']
(node1@localhost)3> node_ring:find(a).
error
```

Whoops, we have inconsistent data across the ring.  Further study of other distributed systems and [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) is necessary before we can decide how we want our little `node_ring` to behave in these different situations (like whether we want it to behave like an AP or a CP system).

Comment: Thanks. You helped me a lot, mainly how to start. This excellent post inspired me. I implement similar distributed ring. Actually, I implement consistent hashing and I try gossip protocol.